# Sum of values in column by row and also selecting other columns in the result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My current query is as follows:

```
select id, quantity, c, d
from table1;
```

This would give me example data as below:

```
id | quantity | c | d
---------------------
1  |    1     | x | y
1  |    3     | x | y
2  |    1     | x | y
2  |    1     | x | y
```

However I want to group by the ID and get the sum of the quantities to be as below:

```
id | quantity | c | d
---------------------
1  |    4     | x | y
2  |    2     | x | y
```

I tried to modify my first query to include a group by on the id and a sum on the quantities:

```
select id, sum(quantity), c, d
from table1
group by id;
```

But I got an error because the other 2 columns are not part of the group by clause. How can I include them?

Answer (score 2):

Simple add they to the group by clause:

```
select id, sum(quantity), c, d from table1 group by id, c, d;
```

Comment: This will yield wrong results in cases of having more then one combination for c,d.

Comment: Yes and no, cause the example data shows the same values for c and d.

Comment: If you intend to show id's sum of quantity to `group by  id, c, d` is WRONG

Answer (score 2):

Using [OVER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) clause make sense here:

```
select id, SUM(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY id), c, d 
from table1
```

Don't forget to get distinct results.
If you have more than one combination of c, d you will need to state explicitly which one you want to choose.

Comment: I will be happy to know why this answer was downvoted

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your answer returns 4 rows, while in the question OP expects to get only 2...